# How to fix 'require() of ES Module not supported' error while updating from Angular 12 to 13?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Require() of ES Module not supported while updating from Angular 12 to 13

I have updated all my packages to support Angular 13, I tried deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, dist and run npm install
but still after complilation in the main.js
platform-browser gets imported by require which could possibly cause this issue

**Version tried**

> Node version - 16.20.0

> TypeScript - 4.4.3, 4.6.0

The error is seen in the console when the app opens after ng serve compiles successfully

> Error: require() of ES Module
> /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/platform-browser.mjs
> not supported. Instead change the require of
> /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/platform-browser.mjs
> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:477:5)
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1009:11)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
> at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
> at o._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2:3109)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at 7258 (main.js:1:1070126)
> at r (runtime.js:1:127)
> at R (main.js:1:2708253)
> at main.js:1:2708270
> at n (runtime.js:1:3008)
> at main.js:1:57

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.2.12",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.8.0",
    "archiver": "^4.0.2",
    "async-waterfall": "^0.1.5",
    "blockly": "^5.20210325.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "downloads-folder": "^3.0.1",
    "electron-json-storage": "^4.5.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.13.0",
    "http-server": "^0.12.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "plotly.js": "^2.9.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "split2": "^3.2.2",
    "systeminformation": "^5.11.9",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "yargs": "^17.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.4.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "^22.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^23.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^5.84.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete node-modules, angular and package-lock.json and run npm i?

Comment: @KrystianChodak -Yes, I have tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, We faced this issue while upgrading Angular from 12 to 13 and we had "type": "commonjs" present in our package.json.

One major change done by the Angular developers is that they were no longer providing the CommonJS modules, instead only ESM modules (MJS files). So, if we try to load Angular 13 packages like core, platform-browser etc. with commonJS syntax (require ('@angular/core')), it will give `require() of ES Module not supported` error.

We updated dependencies like typescript, node and all, reinstalled node modules, and cleared the npm and angular cache multiple times but nothing worked for us.

In our project (Angular + Electron), we were using some of the node modules (like 'os', 'fs' etc) that are usually not available in browsers because of obvious security reasons. So we were using a [custom webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to bundle such node modules. In webpack configuration, we can pass the list of [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) node modules that need to be exposed in the browser. These **externals** list was having @angular packages also (Actually, we had put all node modules using [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) in the externals dependency list). The generated bundle was then having the commonJS imports i.e., `require()` for external dependencies. So, giving us `require() of ES Module not supported` error.

By default, the angular webpack was generating the ESM imports only but because we had specified angular in external dependencies, we were getting that error. So we were left with two options

- Remove angular packages from the externals list. It is recommended to keep this list as small as possible.
- Configure custom builder webpack to generate ESM imports for externals also.

We opted for the first option and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

### REGARDING THE ACTUAl ISSUE

Try updating to `v13.1.4`, I think this will fix it. Had this kind of issue, fixed for me.

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

First of all... **DO NOT DELETE** `package-lock.json` this kind of stuff majority of times happens exactly when you continuesly delete it, there is a `lock` in name for something you know, it holds `exact`, perfectly working dependency tree, while `package.json` holds approximate. This is why you generate node_modules with `npm ci` not with `npm i`, because it will `generate/regenerate` node_modules based on `package-lock` thus firing error if it is not present.

You never ever delete `lock.json` in a project where you have so many 3rd party dependencies. Its not about capability of its regeneration, of course you can regenerate it with `npm i`, the thing is that it will no longer hold the same exact dependency tree, because `npm i` installs packages based on criterion of `^` and `~`. These criterias allow npm to install package update release even if the parent package has not been adapted to use the update.

To give you an idea, its something like this:
Imagine you install a `package X v.1` which uses dependency `package Y v.1`.

Here we go and delete `package-lock` and `use npm i` to regenerate it.

Now it turns out `package X` released an update so now its `v.2`  and needs `package Y v.2`, so `npm i` installs these because of the prefix it has in `package.json`.

And here comes bomb >>> we also have `package C v.1` that previously also used `package Y v.1` as dependency, but now it has a incomplatibility because `package C` continues to be `v.1` but `package Y` is now `v.2`,

This means that in a big project there is very low chance that regenerated `package-lock` will hold the same dependency tree that the previous one. You may fix one conflict by deleting it but you will probably mess up whole depenency tree and you will not be able to run project because you will have a lot of package mismatches and incompatibilities.

You must always fix package issues without deleting `package-lock`, it is the last option if you can even call it an option. Because you can not delete exact versioning of dependency tree where the majority of stuff is OK.

Comment: I tried updating to @angular/cli and @angular-devkit/build-angular to 13..1.4, still facing the same issue. My goal is to update angular all the way to 16 (latest). even if I igonre this in 13 and proceed to 14, I get the same error when I run v14

Comment: Create a stackblitz with your current package.json and i will have a look

Comment: stackblitz for package.json https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3tedsr?file=package.json

Comment: @DaneshwaranM now as your package-lock is already messed up, delete it. then get package.json content from https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-upzha7?file=package.json and run npm install. This should not matter but my node version is v18.10.0.   For me it works...

Comment: Also have this in mind, you are using a lot of deprecated packages and they are the source of your `16 moderate` and `6 high` vulnerabilities.

`@npmcli/move-file, request-promise-native, har-validator, w3c-hr-time, asar, uuid, mumath, electron-osx-sign, request, ecstatic, protractor, popper.js, tslint`, all of these package were deprecated longs ago, they are not maintained so should try your best to removed these dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Node.js version 16 or later installed.
Update the TypeScript version in your project's package.json file to `"typescript": "^4.4.4"` or the latest version compatible with Angular 13.

Update all Angular-related packages in your package.json file to their respective Angular 13 versions.

Ensure that your project uses the ECMAScript modules (ESM) format by adding `"type": "module"` to your `tsconfig.json` file.

Replace any instances of `require()` with the import statement throughout your codebase, as Angular 13 uses ESM.

Run `npm install` to install the updated packages.
Fix any other compatibility issues or deprecations mentioned in the Angular Update Guide for migrating from 12 to 13.

Build and run your application to verify that the issue is resolved.
Remember to always refer to the official Angular documentation and update guides for detailed instructions on how to update your specific project.